# Adobe AIR app is hardly clickable at the upper right corner only on iOS

Tags: android, ios, iphone, apache-flex, air

I've build Adobe AIR Flex app that is working on Android in Google Play and on iOS in Apple Store.
But **on iPhone 5 - the upper right corner buttons are very very hard to click.**

[image]

The flex application is done well - there is nothing on top of the buttons, and it works perfectly on Android, but on iOS the buttons kind of work after 5-10 times of trying to click them.

Can it be because of the top bar that iPhone can drag down in the native screen ?

Here is my [monopoly](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rento/id948418419) app on iOS so you can see it for yourself.
And here is the [monopoly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.bg.lan.Monopoli) in Google Play - working without problems.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using GESTURE?

Comment: No, regular mouse events (mxml click attribute)

Comment: If you use the the default touch handling - the touches aren't sensitive.  You have to code your own touch handling to get it nice and sensitive like the ipad os (a very light touch):  Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT;

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Air Flex into can you increase touch area of button? You just put image on center of button. Some thing like your button size is 44*44. But you should set image 30*30. So By default touch area are increases. If it is possible then take this layer on top of all layer. May be this idea is helpful for you..

Comment: Thank you but is not the hit area that is problematic. If the button was places below or somewhere not at the top line of the app - it would not have problem

Comment: @DeyanVitanov, It just happen with iPhone5 or earlier or later devices? can you test with other devices?

Comment: With any android device it works fine, but on iOS is not OK :/